# Merge two PHP array by ID

Tags: php, arrays, merge, union

I have two array get from two foreach loop.

```
Array ([0] => Young Boys [1] => Vidi FC [2] => Ajax [3] => Independiente)

Array ([0] => Dinamo Zagreb [1] => AEK Athens [2] => Dynamo Kyiv [3] => Santos FC)
```

PHP CODE

```
foreach($html->find('.col-home a') as $element)  
    $array1[] = $element->plaintext;

foreach($html->find('.col-guest a') as $element2)  
    $array2[] = $element2->plaintext;
```

How can I get this results?

```
Young Boys - Dinamo Zagreb
Vidi FC - AEK Athens
Ajax - Dynamo Kyiv
Independiente - Santos FC
```

thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Loop with a `for` loop through one array and use the index to access the other and combine them in a result array.

https://3v4l.org/jkhpK

```
$a1 = ['Young Boys', 'Vidi FC', 'Ajax', 'Independiente'];
$a2 = ['Dinamo Zagreb', 'AEK Athens', 'Dynamo Kyiv', 'Santos FC'];
$result = [];
for($i = 0; $i < count($a1); $i++) {
    $result[] = $a1[$i] . ' - ' . $a2[$i];
}

var_dump($result);
```

**Output for 5.6.30, hhvm-3.18.5 - 3.22.0, 7.0.28 - 7.3.0beta2**

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(26) "Young Boys - Dinamo Zagreb"
  [1]=>
  string(20) "Vidi FC - AEK Athens"
  [2]=>
  string(18) "Ajax - Dynamo Kyiv"
  [3]=>
  string(25) "Independiente - Santos FC"
}
```

EDIT: You might aswell add an `isset` check in the loop to make sure you don't access an index that is not available in the 2nd array like

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($a1); $i++) {
    if(isset($a1[$i]) && isset($a2[$i])) { 
        $result[] = $a1[$i] . ' - ' . $a2[$i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Go through one array and find item from the other with the same index:

```
foreach ($array1 as $index => $val1)
    echo $val1.' - '.$array2[$index].'<br />';
```

If You are not sure that the arrays are of the same length, You can use the longer (or shorter) one:

```
$count = max(count($array1), count($array2));
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
    echo (isset($array1[$i])?$array1[$i]:'').' - '.(isset($array2[$i])?$array2[$i]:'').'<br />';
```

EDIT: Used `isset()` instead of `@`, thanks to @Xatenev's comment.

Comment: Why do you recommend error suppressing instead of adding isset?

Comment: @Xatenev: Because of bad habit :-( `isset()` would be much faster and overall better, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $a = array( 'Young Boys' ,'Vidi FC' , 'Ajax' , 'Independiente');
   $b = array( 'Dinamo Zagreb', 'AEK Athens', 'Dynamo Kyiv', 'Santos FC');
   foreach ($a as $key => $val){
   echo $val.' - '.$b[$key];
   echo '<br />'; 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take longest Array in foreach.

```
foreach($array2 as $k =>$v){    
    $concrat[$v] = $array1[$k];
}
```